# How to associate tables on insert in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have a 1:1 relationship between a Customer and a product. So I am adding a table for both. In my LINQ to SQL file I have everything porperly set with keys and the association in the .dbml.

Now I Insert two tables that should be associated:

```
    CustomerDataContext dc = new CustomerDataContext();
    Table<Customer> customers = dc.GetTable<Customer>();
    Table<Product> products= dc.GetTable<Product>();

    Customer newCustomer = new Customer ();
    Product newProduct   = new Product();


    customers.InsertOnSubmit(newCustomer);
    products.InsertOnSubmit(newProduct);
    customers.Context.SubmitChanges();
```

So how can I establish the association at this point? So when I query against this Customer table I can call the associated Product like, Customer.Product?

Is this even possible?

greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CustomerDataContext dc = new CustomerDataContext();
Table<Customer> customers = dc.GetTable<Customer>();
Table<Product> products= dc.GetTable<Product>();
Table<ProductConsumer> ProductConsumers= dc.GetTable<ProductConsumer>();

Customer newCustomer = new Customer ();
Product newProduct   = new Product();


customers.InsertOnSubmit(newCustomer);
products.InsertOnSubmit(newProduct);
customers.Context.SubmitChanges();
products.Context.SubmitChanges();

//Now insert associations
ProductConsumer= new ProductConsumer();
ProductConsumer.Consumer= newCustomer ;
ProductConsumer.Product= newProduct  ;


ProductConsumers.InsertOnSubmit(ProductConsumer)
ProductConsumers.Context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: How many times are you going to submit changes?  Isn't once enough? :)

Comment: What is ProductConsumer supposed to be? Another Table?

Comment: yes it is your association table (one column for consumerID and another for ProductID)

Comment: So I have to create another table inbetween of each tableassociation?

Comment: I thought LINQ would somehow handle this for me :)

Comment: ;-) have you a foreign key in product table to reference your consumer table?

Comment: I didn't enter one. But after ORM entity classes have the foreign key I thought.

Comment: if you have a many to many relationship you have to create another table but in case of one to many relationship (that is a foreign key referenced Consumer in product table you have only to set IDconsumer in foreign key column of your product table

Comment: something like newProduct.CustomerID = newCustomer.ID

Comment: in your orm (entity?) you have to make the mapping see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2007/05/10/mapping-101-part-2-association-mapping.aspx